# How to Next.js 7 support for css-modules & normal css at the same time, same behaviour as CRA

Tags: next.js

I want Next.js 7 support for css-modules & normal css at the same time, same behaviour as CRA.

I found this: https://gist.github.com/Grsmto/8e7ade37862f1c8b4d019da8dd423450
. But it not work with NextJS 7. They use mini-css-extract-plugin there.

So what's the solution ?

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps:

- Add your normal css file in `Head` component (`next/head`) for every required component

  - You can directly put it in the `_app.js` file if it is common between all
- Then load your `css module` in `next.config.js` file as explained [here](https://github.com/zeit/next-plugins/tree/master/packages/next-css#with-css-modules)